# Configuring PhpStorm for using built-in web server in OS X Mojave

Tags: php, phpstorm

The question is the following: what are the **minimal-required** steps to have PhpStorm configured for using built-in web-server on Mojave system?

I mean, installing the least possible additional software on my system (just started from scratch recently and want to keep number of installed software at the minimal level).

I have `php` and `php-fpm` installed "out of the box":

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.1.19 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2018 18:03:17) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

$ php-fpm -v
PHP 7.1.19 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Aug 17 2018 18:03:20)
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Still, when trying to configure "PHP interpreter" in PhpStorm, I end up with this error message:

> php-cgi not found: Please ensure that configured PHP Interpreter built
>   as CGI program (--enable-fastcgi was specified)

Doesn't `php-fpm` implement Fast-CGI?…

Comment: Is there a way to install specifically "php-cgi", without pulling the whole "php replacement" from homebrew? (since I already have PHP pre-shipped)

Comment: Why not try Docker? Ideal solution for your needs (keep minimal software on your host OS).

Comment: @LazyOne Docker is very slow on my system (4G RAM). Even with ":delegated" flag on mounted volumes.. Part of the reason is that the web application I'm working with is critical to FS operations.

So, `php -S localhost:8000` feels much better. But at this moment I'd like to check PHP Storm's "Built in web-server" way :-)

Comment: PhpStorm's built-in web server is quite simple .. and requires using URL like `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/path/to/file.php`. So it's suitable for rather simple things only. I suggest using PHP's own built-in web server (the one you have mentioned: `php -S localhost:8000`) -- **those are different things** (not sure what exactly you were referring to in first place, but I thought you were talking about PhpStorm's own web server).

Comment: For the 2nd one you need to look at this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/run-debug-configuration-php-built-in-web-server.html . If that's you were using ... then AFAIK it should work as long as you can use `php -S localhost:8000` in terminal.